# Creating/editing mxgraph models using Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, mxgraph

Can mxgraph models be created, edited or converted from JSON or XML data to mxgraph format using Python? If so how can it be done?, I searched on various sites but could not find a solution (an example JSON data);

```
  {
    name: 'Globals',    
    parentObjects: []
  },

  {
    name: 'Customer',
    included: true,    
    parentObjects: [
      {
        name: 'Globals',
      }
    ],
  },

  {
    name: 'Product',
    included: true,    
    parentObjects: [
      {
        name: 'Globals',
      }
    ],
  },

  {
    name: 'Transaction',
    included: true,    
    parentObjects: [
      {
        name: 'Customer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Product',
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "uniform" way of using mxgraph... You can create various types of nodes with various shapes... MxGraph allows you to import and export graphs in JSON and XML format, but first of all you need to create one in a JSON or XML format compatible with MxGraph to be read.

Here you can find an example of code importing to and from JSON:
[Example](https://codepen.io/Gatcha/pen/oYexEB)

As you can see in the JSON you need to specify the various aspects of a node (geometry, parent, edges, connectability, etc.). Similar with XML...

I'm not an expert in Python but what you are supposed to do is to convert your JSON into something that MxGraph can actually read...

Example JSON:

```
{
    "graph": [
        {
            "value": {
                "name": "Daffy Duck"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": 90,
                "y": 60,
                "width": 120,
                "height": 30,
                "relative": false,
                "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                "alternateBounds": null,
                "sourcePoint": null,
                "targetPoint": null,
                "points": null,
                "offset": null
            },
            "id": "2",
            "vertex": true,
            "connectable": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": null,
            "target": null,
            "edges": [
                {
                    "value": "Edge",
                    "geometry": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "relative": true
                    },
                    "id": "4",
                    "edge": true,
                    "parent": "1",
                    "source": "2",
                    "target": "3",
                    "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
                }
            ],
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#6"
        },
        {
            "value": {
                "name": "Bugs Bunny"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": 1020,
                "y": 60,
                "width": 120,
                "height": 30,
                "relative": false,
                "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                "alternateBounds": null,
                "sourcePoint": null,
                "targetPoint": null,
                "points": null,
                "offset": null
            },
            "id": "3",
            "vertex": true,
            "connectable": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": null,
            "target": null,
            "edges": [
                {
                    "value": "Edge",
                    "geometry": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "relative": true
                    },
                    "id": "4",
                    "edge": true,
                    "parent": "1",
                    "source": "2",
                    "target": "3",
                    "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
                }
            ],
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#8"
        },
        {
            "value": "Edge",
            "geometry": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0,
                "relative": true
            },
            "id": "4",
            "edge": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "2",
            "target": "3",
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
        },
        {
            "value": {
                "name": "Elmer Fudd"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": 90,
                "y": 220,
                "width": 120,
                "height": 30,
                "relative": false,
                "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                "alternateBounds": null,
                "sourcePoint": null,
                "targetPoint": null,
                "points": null,
                "offset": null
            },
            "id": "5",
            "vertex": true,
            "connectable": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": null,
            "target": null,
            "edges": [
                {
                    "value": "Edge",
                    "geometry": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "relative": true
                    },
                    "id": "7",
                    "edge": true,
                    "parent": "1",
                    "source": "5",
                    "target": "6",
                    "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
                }
            ],
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#9"
        },
        {
            "value": {
                "name": "Tasmanian Devil"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": 1020,
                "y": 220,
                "width": 120,
                "height": 30,
                "relative": false,
                "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                "alternateBounds": null,
                "sourcePoint": null,
                "targetPoint": null,
                "points": null,
                "offset": null
            },
            "id": "6",
            "vertex": true,
            "connectable": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": null,
            "target": null,
            "edges": [
                {
                    "value": "Edge",
                    "geometry": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "relative": true
                    },
                    "id": "7",
                    "edge": true,
                    "parent": "1",
                    "source": "5",
                    "target": "6",
                    "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
                }
            ],
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#11"
        },
        {
            "value": "Edge",
            "geometry": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0,
                "relative": true
            },
            "id": "7",
            "edge": true,
            "parent": "1",
            "source": "5",
            "target": "6",
            "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However the project I am working on, needs a Pythonic way to do it. Great if someone can give a clue on how to do that. Are there existing methods to do that or do we have to implement a method in Python?

Comment: interesting I am currently searching the same. Thought mxGraph is in the frontend so generating a JSON from an API in DJANGO or Tornado should be ease @marco thanks